# sql concatenation blank between plus signs +

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I received statement block looking like the following:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @ResultVar Varchar(2000)
SET @ResultVar = '('
SELECT @ResultVar = @ResultVar + Convert(varchar,Account) +  + ' '
FROM tbAccount
WHERE ((AccountID = @AccountID)

SET @ResultVar = Replace(RTrim(@ResultVar) + ')', ' ', ', ')

RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

My question: was the plus sign "+" after code "Convert(varchar,Account)" needed or just a typo since there's nothing between two "+"?

Comment: It's either a typo, or the developer intended to put in a blank ...but was being "overly clever".  Either way: if you really want a blank, I'd change the query to make the intent explicit :)

Comment: @paulsm4 what is blank for? I searched through tutorial but couldn't find any clue

Comment: The LINK with article title "SQL Server: +(unary) operator on non-numeric Strings" seems to answer my question. The article indicated it's a bug. The + sign was not needed but still compiled. Hope it helps whoever has the same question in the future.